# How can i find the output amps of an transformer?

Tags: voltage, current, transformer

Here is the transformer with the known specifications.
[image: Here is the transformer with the known specifications]

Comment: No you can't, not from that information alone. You need to know what load is connected to the secondary. If it's open circuit for example, then you know the output current is 0. (It's also a dumb design of transformer :  the impedance ratio should be the square of the turns ratio). Find better material to learn from.

Comment: @user_1818839 I think the ohms refers to the DC resistance of each winding but, that is also somewhat flawed because you'd expect the secondary to be made of thicker magnet wire hence it will be proportionately lower in resistance due to it being thicker.

Comment: Your numbers seem to be wrong anyway.  In Europe the voltage is 230 V, not 220 V. With 230 V primary and 1400 to 200 turns, the secondary voltage should be about 33 V.

Comment: Measure the "core" section. one will have an approximative idea of product VA.

Comment: @Andy that thicker wire is how the squaring in the winding impedance is achieved. Of course it won't be exactly the square, as it's constrained by the available wire gauges.

Comment: It is not clear what the parameters for the question are.  Is it the short-circuit current?  If so there are problems with the question.  Is the question really what secondary current would result in 24 VAC (taking into account the impedances) at the output?

Answer (score 2):

My answer is based on these assumptions:

- You are asking about the rated output current of the transformer. Normally this is not given directly. Instead, power handling numbers (in VA or W) should have been given and printed somewhere on the transformer.
- The secondary voltage is the rated secondary voltage. Rated secondary voltage is the secondary voltage when it's fully loaded.

If I'm correct then you should have indicated these in your question.

From the numbers, the unloaded voltage is

$$
\frac{V_s}{V_p}=\frac{N_s}{N_p}\\
\Rightarrow V_s=\frac{200}{1400}\cdot 220=31.4V
$$

The rated output voltage is the voltage when it's fully loaded. So there is a drop across the DC resistance when the secondary is fully loaded:

$$
V_{sdrop}=(31.4-25)=6.4V=I_{rated}\cdot R_{sec}
$$

If the 10R resistance given for the secondary is correct then the rated current should be something like 640mA. So the calculated power rating is \$P_r=25V\cdot0.64A=16\ VA\$

Again, this answer is based on the assumptions.

Comment: The 6.4V drop is also partly due to \$R_{pri}\$ so VA rated will be slightly less.